# How to Use Windows Firewall Rules While Port Forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I've set up port forwarding on my router to my Windows PC. I've created an inbound rule in the Windows Firewall that allows connections only for the private profile and I've verified the specified port is open when I connect my PC through that profile.

The problem is that the port stays open for all three profiles. It stays open whether I enable or disable the related firewall rule. It even stays open if I delete the related firewall rule.

I want the port to open when the Windows Firewall activates the private profile. I also want the port to close when the domain or public profile is activated.

I've read through dozens of articles and forums but I don't think I know enough about the subject to use the right keywords...

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I read your question a few times, I'm still not sure what you want to do, a diagram might help.

Comment: Hi Albin, thanks for the feedback. I've tried to make my question easier to understand. Does that help?

Comment: Not really, it's too unspecific, what do you mean by "I've opened a port on my router", "The port works", "the Windows Firewall has no effect on the port", etc.? I also don't understand what you mean by "I want the port to open and close based on the Windows Firewall profile".

Comment: Thank you, Albin. You've helped me explain my situation more clearly. I've rewritten it once more based on your feedback. Is it better now?

Comment: It's better now, I've posted an answer. I also changed the first paragraph of your question as well, please check if my edit is correct.

Comment: What port are you connecting to the Windows machine on? I suspect you are using a port that has an implicit Windows Firewall rule which allowing the app or protocol also allows that port. Maybe it's due to the port you are trying to open on the Windows machine in particular. If you have control over the port, use a different port if possible. Otherwise, it depends on the port you are connecting to whether the rule is enabled or disabled. Something else rule wise is allowing it thru, again... what port are you connecting to exactly?

Comment: Thanks, Pimp Juice IT. I'm using port 9999. I tried port 8889 as well but it had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup of your firewall might need some "cleaning", there might be a rule that allows traffic for that port/application etc. or the port wasn't closed by the firewall in the first place: by default Windows firewall blocks incoming traffic, but this can be changed for each profile individually. You can do basic testing by deactivating or by deleting the firewall rules (export them as a backup first) until you find the conflicting rule. Alternatively, you can check the rules one by one.

The easiest solution might be just to do "the opposite" and to add a rule to block traffic to the port in the profiles where you don't want the port to be open (in your case domain or public). Make sure the blocking rule takes higher priority than any conflicting rules that might be in there ([see here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13894.troubleshooting-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-in-windows-server-2012.aspx#Rules_are_evaluated_in_a_specific_order)), or to avoid conflict altogether temp. deactivate or delete any allow rules (see above).

Comment: Thanks, Albin. Your edits are correct. I checked the "Local Port" column in the advanced settings of the Windows Firewall but I didn't see anything that used the same port (9999). Based on the link you sent, could the port forward be considered the "Authenticated bypass rules" rule type? Which would take precedence over the "Allow rules" rule type? Could that explain why the port is open when there isn't a firewall rule for it?

Comment: @TheAltruist No, the port forward on your router will not effect the firewall rules. And looking for port rules is not enough, you can set rules based on all kind of things, not only ports. To make sure I would advice you to make the test first (either disable all "allow" rules or delete them temporally). Also what is the "main" setting of the firewall for that profile? Blocking all incoming traffic?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. It worked! I disabled all the "Allow" rules and the port closed. I enabled the related firewall rule and the port opened. I disabled the related firewall rule and the port closed again. What would you recommend I do to find the cause?

Comment: @TheAltruist depends on how many rules you have and how well you know your rules. If you know them or with a few rules, I would just check them individually. With a lot of unknown rules: disable 50%, if the port is still open disable 50% of the remaining etc. ... until you find the relevant rule

Comment: Ok, I can figure out the rest. Thank you, Albin!

Comment: @TheAltruist glad I could help